# C++ what do do when namespace, classname and namespace::classname clash

Tags: c++, namespaces

I inherited some badly named code and got lucky when I received an third party library that made my life even more complicated.  This is what I ended up with.

```
class Something; // third party library

namespace Something {
  class Something;
  class Templated<class TemplateClass>;
}
```

Now I need to use the class "Something" from the third party library as the TemplateClass parameter for a new class under namespace Something.  I thought this should work

```
class Something; // third party library

namespace Something {
  class Something;
  class Templated<class TemplateClass>;

  class Impl : public Templated< ::Something > {}
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like it.  The only way I got it to compile was

```
class Something; // third party library

class Something2 : public Something {} // dirty hack

namespace Something {
  class Something;
  class Templated<class TemplateClass>;

  class Impl : public Templated< Something2 > {}
}
```

But I don't really like it.  There **must** be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use another namespace:

```
class Something; // third party library

namespace third_party{
  using ::Something;
}

namespace Something {
  class Something;
  class Templated<class TemplateClass>;

  class Impl : public Templated< ::third_party::Something > {}
}
```

In general, though, I think naming your class and namespace exactly the same is a very bad idea.

Comment: Just a side-note: In Google C++ style guide, they require namespace names to start with a _small letter_. That way, it never clashes with a class name.

Comment: @Hindol: Google's C++ style guide is very domain specific for Google's codebase (they don't allow exceptions because their legacy code isn't exception safe). Also, [it mostly sucks](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/why-google-style-guide-sucks-roughly). :)

Comment: @Hindol: I really like this approach.  What's the link to the guide?

Comment: @Hindol I wouldn't take a guide that is afraid of unsigned integers and exceptions too seriously for my own projects. It is *Google*'s style guide used by *Google* for *Google*'s software, nothing more.

Comment: @krico Here is the [link](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml). But as others said, don't follow it blindly.

Comment: @Xeo Can you suggest a better style-guide? A guide with explanations of why one is better over the other is preferred.

Comment: @Hindol: There is no "general purpose" style guide. It's always domain specific for your code base.

Comment: @Hindol Lack of a better alternative doesn't magically make existing solutions good. It's the best option when working for *Google* and on *Google*'s projects. For everything else it is just **no** option, since it has never been intended to be used for anything non-*Google*.